# Getting the menu to start at the start of the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

So, I have this menu which is this project [here](https://github.com/burczyk/SwiftTeamSelect) but just update to the latest syntax of swift. the problem I have is that every time I load up the scene in which the menu is located in, it starts in the middle of the array instead of at the start of it like so.

[image]

What i'm trying to achieve is so when I load up the scene with the menu in it i want it to start at the start of array instead of the middle of the array the main functions that place and position the spritenodes in the scene are as follows:

```
func createPlayers() {

    for _ in 0..<9 {
        let player = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue , size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 200))
        players.append(player)
    }
}


func placePlayersOnPositions() {

    for i in 0..<players.count/2 {
        players[i].position = CGPoint(x: leftGuide, y: size.height/2)
    }

    players[players.count/2].position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

    for i in players.count/2 + 1..<players.count {
        players[i].position = CGPoint(x: rightGuide, y: size.height/2)
    }

    for player in players {
        player.setScale(calculateScaleForX(x: player.position.x))
        self.addChild(player)
    }   
}
```

How can I modify the above code so that it starts the menu at the start of the array instead of in the middle like this:

[image]

**Here is the full menu code:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

enum Zone {
    case Left, Center, Right
}

var players = [SKSpriteNode]()

var leftPlayer: SKSpriteNode?
var centerPlayer: SKSpriteNode?
var rightPlayer: SKSpriteNode?

var leftGuide : CGFloat {
    return round(view!.bounds.width / 6.0)
}

var rightGuide : CGFloat {
    return view!.bounds.width - leftGuide
}

var gap : CGFloat {
    return (size.width / 2 - leftGuide) / 2
}


// Initialization

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size:size)
    createPlayers()
    centerPlayer = players[players.count/2]
    setLeftAndRightPlayers()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    placePlayersOnPositions()
    calculateZIndexesForPlayers()
}

func createPlayers() {

    for _ in 0..<9 {
        let player = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue , size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 200))
        players.append(player)
    }
}

func placePlayersOnPositions() {

    for i in 0..<players.count/2 {
        players[i].position = CGPoint(x: leftGuide, y: size.height/2)
    }

    players[players.count/2].position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

    for i in players.count/2 + 1..<players.count {
        players[i].position = CGPoint(x: rightGuide, y: size.height/2)
    }

    for player in players {
        player.setScale(calculateScaleForX(x: player.position.x))
        self.addChild(player)
    }

}


// Helper functions

func calculateScaleForX(x:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let minScale = CGFloat(0.5)

    if x <= leftGuide || x >= rightGuide {
        return minScale
    }

    if x < size.width/2 {
        let a = 1.0 / (size.width - 2 * leftGuide)
        let b = 0.5 - a * leftGuide

        return (a * x + b)
    }

    let a = 1.0 / (frame.size.width - 2 * rightGuide)
    let b = 0.5 - a * rightGuide

    return (a * x + b)
}

func calculateZIndexesForPlayers() {
    var playerCenterIndex : Int = players.count / 2

    for i in 0..<players.count {
        if centerPlayer == players[i] {
            playerCenterIndex = i
        }
    }

    for i in 0...playerCenterIndex {
        players[i].zPosition = CGFloat(i)
    }

    for i in playerCenterIndex+1..<players.count {
        players[i].zPosition = centerPlayer!.zPosition * 2 - CGFloat(i)
    }

}

func movePlayerToX(player: SKSpriteNode, x: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval) {
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: x, duration: duration)
    let scaleAction = SKAction.scale(to: calculateScaleForX(x: x), duration: duration)

    player.run(SKAction.group([moveAction, scaleAction]))
}

func movePlayerByX(player: SKSpriteNode, x: CGFloat) {
    let duration = 0.01

    if player.frame.midX <= rightGuide && player.frame.midX >= leftGuide {
        player.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: x, y: 0, duration: duration), completion: {
            player.setScale(self.calculateScaleForX(x: player.frame.midX))
        })

        if player.frame.midX < leftGuide {
            player.position = CGPoint(x: leftGuide, y: player.position.y)
        } else if player.frame.midX > rightGuide {
            player.position = CGPoint(x: rightGuide, y: player.position.y)
        }
    }
}

func zoneOfCenterPlayer() -> Zone {
    let gap = size.width / 2 - leftGuide

    switch centerPlayer!.frame.midX {

    case let x where x < leftGuide + gap/2:
        return .Left

    case let x where x > rightGuide - gap/2:
        return .Right

    default: return .Center

    }
}

func setLeftAndRightPlayers() {
    var playerCenterIndex : Int = players.count / 2

    for i in 0..<players.count {
        if centerPlayer == players[i] {
            playerCenterIndex = i
        }
    }

    if playerCenterIndex > 0 && playerCenterIndex < players.count {
        leftPlayer = players[playerCenterIndex-1]
    } else {
        leftPlayer = nil
    }

    if playerCenterIndex > -1 && playerCenterIndex < players.count-1 {
        rightPlayer = players[playerCenterIndex+1]
    } else {
        rightPlayer = nil
    }
}



// Touch interactions


 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let node = self.atPoint(touch.location(in: self))

    if node == centerPlayer {
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.5, duration: 0.15)
        let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: 0.15)

        centerPlayer!.run(fadeOut, completion: { self.centerPlayer!.run(fadeIn) })
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let duration = 0.01
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let newPosition = touch.location(in: self)
    let oldPosition = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
    let xTranslation = newPosition.x - oldPosition.x

    if centerPlayer!.frame.midX > size.width/2 {
        if (leftPlayer != nil) {
            let actualTranslation = leftPlayer!.frame.midX + xTranslation > leftGuide ? xTranslation : leftGuide - leftPlayer!.frame.midX
            movePlayerByX(player: leftPlayer!, x: actualTranslation)
        }
    } else {
        if (rightPlayer != nil) {
            let actualTranslation = rightPlayer!.frame.midX + xTranslation < rightGuide ? xTranslation : rightGuide - rightPlayer!.frame.midX
            movePlayerByX(player: rightPlayer!, x: actualTranslation)
        }
    }

    movePlayerByX(player: centerPlayer!, x: xTranslation)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
//func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let duration = 0.25

    switch zoneOfCenterPlayer() {

    case .Left:
        if (rightPlayer != nil) {
            movePlayerToX(player: centerPlayer!, x: leftGuide, duration: duration)
            if (leftPlayer != nil) {
                movePlayerToX(player: leftPlayer!, x: leftGuide, duration: duration)
            }
            if (rightPlayer != nil) {
                movePlayerToX(player: rightPlayer!, x: size.width/2, duration: duration)
            }

            centerPlayer = rightPlayer
            setLeftAndRightPlayers()
        } else {
            movePlayerToX(player: centerPlayer!, x: size.width/2, duration: duration)
        }

    case .Right:
        if (leftPlayer != nil) {
            movePlayerToX(player: centerPlayer!, x: rightGuide, duration: duration)
            if (rightPlayer != nil) {
                movePlayerToX(player: rightPlayer!, x: rightGuide, duration: duration)
            }
            if (leftPlayer != nil) {
                movePlayerToX(player: leftPlayer!, x: size.width/2, duration: duration)
            }

            centerPlayer = leftPlayer
            setLeftAndRightPlayers()
        } else {
            movePlayerToX(player: centerPlayer!, x: size.width/2, duration: duration)
        }

    case .Center:
        movePlayerToX(player: centerPlayer!, x: size.width/2, duration: duration)
        if (leftPlayer != nil) {
            movePlayerToX(player: leftPlayer!, x: leftGuide, duration: duration)
        }
        if (rightPlayer != nil) {
            movePlayerToX(player: rightPlayer!, x: rightGuide, duration: duration)
        }
    }

    calculateZIndexesForPlayers()
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had just a quick peek and did not try it, but this might work

```
func placePlayersOnPositions() {

        players.first?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

        if players.count > 1 {
            for i in 1..<players.count {
                players[i].position = CGPoint(x: rightGuide, y: size.height/2)
            }        
        }

        for player in players {
            player.setScale(calculateScaleForX(x: player.position.x))
            self.addChild(player)
        } 
}
```

Comment: yeah that worked but i also changed the init value on the center player to centerPlayer = players[0] like the other answer said to do also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you will have to change your `init` function to not hard code the center player to count divided by 2 but rather to player zero.

from

```
centerPlayer = players[players.count/2]
```

to

```
centerPlayer = players[0]
```